# CORS issues with vue/node to rack/thin via nginx

Tags: vuejs2, cors, rack

I had this working properly and all of a sudden during a restart stopped working and I can't get to the bottom of what happened.

Basically, vue/node (dev) mode is using http but the ajax uses https to the server.
Server responds with all headers including Access-Control-Request-Origin and I can see json data response from the server in the firefox dev tools
But for some reason it throws an Error: Network Error alert. Inspecting in dev tools I find

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://r.roller.lan/workstations?session_token=2de63puojmt3ubkfp94c3ohm45. (Reason: CORS header “Access-Control-Allow-Origin” does not match “https://devv.roller.lan:8080”)

I am making request from http://devv.roller.lan:8080 and somewhere in the chain gets translated to https:// which doesn't match?

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar error a while back which was caused by a plugin. Have you tried disabling all plugins / running in incognito mode? It could also be caused by your routing. If you set up your server to route all http calls to https then you may see something like this as well.

Comment: I tried with Option in FF "Restart with Add-ons Disabled" and basically FF tells me  that is enetring "Safe Mode" and Voila Everything Works as expected.
Thank you Justin for your hep, much appreciated.

Comment: Check out something like [Nginx Reverse Proxy](https://blog.boatswain.io/post/setup-cors-in-nginx-with-proxypass-upstream/).  If you're using a dev server, you could proxy your requests instead.  With that said you want your backend to support the Access-Control headers as by default (for security reasons), it is blocked.

Comment: Thank you very much Koshux. Everything works as expected after I added highlighted portion from the article to the nginx conf.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works as expected after I added highlighted portion from the Nginx Reverse Proxy article Koshux referenced to the nginx conf.